# Create canvas element when clicking on one element then click on that element

Tags: javascript, canvas

I click on the green circle to create a canvas element, a yellow circle, but when I create the isPointinPath variable with the if-statement, I get an error. I want to create a new element once a I click on the green circle and I want to be able to click on that new element. So far, I can only create it. How do I make it clickable? Are there other approaches to this?

\

```
<!DOCTYPE html\>

<canvas id ="canvas" style="border: solid 5px blue";\>\</canvas\>

    //declare canvas

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 800;

function circle_factory(circle_var, x, y, start, end, color) {

circle_var = new Path2D()
circle_var.arc(x, y, 50, start, end \* Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = color;
circle_var.closePath
ctx.fill(circle_var);

}

//circle 2
var circle2 = new Path2D();
circle2.arc(250, 75, 50, 0, 2 \* Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
circle2.closePath
ctx.fill(circle2);

var circle_1 = new circle_factory(circle_1, 510, 75, 0, 2, 'orange')

canvas.addEventListener('click', (event) =\> {

    circle_2_click = ctx.isPointInPath(circle2, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)
    
    if (circle_2_click) {
        var circle_yellow = new circle_factory(circle_yellow, 640, 75, 0, 2, 'yellow')
    
        var circle_yellow_click = ctx.isPointInPath(circle_yellow, event.offsetX, event.offsetY)
    
        if (circle_yellow_click) {console.log('it works')}
    
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are trying to pass the `circle_yellow` variable into the `circle_factory` function as the first argument. However, `circle_yellow` is not yet defined at that point, so it will be `undefined`.

One solution is to remove the first argument from the `circle_factory` function and have it return the created Path2D object. Then, you can assign the returned value to the `circle_yellow` variable.

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: solid 5px blue"></canvas>

<script>
  //declare canvas
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 1000;
  canvas.height = 800;

  function circle_factory(x, y, start, end, color) {
    const circle_var = new Path2D();
    circle_var.arc(x, y, 50, start, end * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    circle_var.closePath();
    ctx.fill(circle_var);
    return circle_var;
  }

  //circle 2
  const circle2 = circle_factory(250, 75, 0, 2, "green");

  const circle_1 = circle_factory(510, 75, 0, 2, "orange");

  canvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const circle_2_click = ctx.isPointInPath(circle2, event.offsetX, event.offsetY);

    if (circle_2_click) {
      const circle_yellow = circle_factory(640, 75, 0, 2, "yellow");

      const circle_yellow_click = ctx.isPointInPath(circle_yellow, event.offsetX, event.offsetY);

      if (circle_yellow_click) {
        console.log("it works");
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

To make the new circle clickable, you can add another event listener for the canvas element that checks if the click is inside the new circle's path:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
const circle_2_click = ctx.isPointInPath(circle2, event.offsetX, 
event.offsetY);

if (circle_2_click) {
const circle_yellow = circle_factory(640, 75, 0, 2, "yellow");

canvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const circle_yellow_click = ctx.isPointInPath(circle_yellow, 
event.offsetX, event.offsetY);

  if (circle_yellow_click) {
    console.log("it works");
  }
});
}});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could nest event listeners like that.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

All of your (currently) four answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.